# render details in django email

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django celery to send emails when the manufacturing date is none. I'm successfully sending emails, however in the email, I also want to include the order ID of that particular order that has no manufacturing date, how can I do that?

```
@shared_task
def check_for_orders():
    orders = Order.objects.all()
    for order in orders:
        if order.manu_date is None:
            send_mail('Manufacturing Reminder',
                ' {{order.id}} manufacturing date is none ',
                'dummyguy1680@gmail.com',
                ['dummyguy1680@gmail.com'])
            return None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options. The easiest way is probably to use string formatting:

```
@shared_task
def check_for_orders():
    orders = Order.objects.all()
    for order in orders:
        if order.manu_date is None:
            body = '{} manufacturing date is none '.format(order.id),
            send_mail('Manufacturing Reminder',
                body
                'dummyguy1680@gmail.com',
                ['dummyguy1680@gmail.com'])
            return None
```

If you are using Python 3.6 or newer, you can also use an f-string:

```
body = f'{order.id} manufacturing date is none '
```

You could read a Django template in a string:

```
from django.template import Template, Context
..
t = Template("{{order.id}} manufacturing date is none")
c = Context({"order": "order"})
body t.render(c)
```

But in this case, it might be preferable to put your message template in a separate file and render it with [django.template.loader.render_to_string](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string):

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

body = render_to_string('manufacturing_reminder.txt', {'order': order})
```

In `manufacturing_reminder.txt`:

```
{{order.id}} manufacturing date is none
```

**Note:** If you are sending HTML emails, don't use string formatting to avoid code injection vulnerabilities. Use Django templates, which take care of proper escaping.

Comment: string formatting allows multiple values, e.g.: `'{} from {} manufacturing date is none '.format(order.id, order.date_created)'`